# How to change env variables programmatically in Windows?

Tags: android, windows, sh, environment

I have two  big files with environment variables for Windows according to testing and production build variants for an android file. I need to run the production env variables files to test the app in production but how do I do this?

This is how the file looks (prod_env.sh) :

```
#Prod
export BASE_URL='"https://ma.aycrd.com/"'
export IMAGE_URL='"https://getapp.aycrd.com/"'
```

I have a lot of lines to run it manually. If I run `source prod_env.sh` it doesn't work, what is the way to make it work?